# C++: Receiving "couldn't deduce template parameter" error in template quicksort function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, quicksort, template-function

I'm creating a templated quicksort function which should allow me to quicksort a custom-made doubly linked list class using iterators. I'm getting the error

```
In file included from main.cpp:21.0:
quicksort.h: In instantiation of 'void quicksort(listclass&) [with
listclass = inkist<int>]':
main.cpp:156:23: required from here
quicksort.h:36:33: error: no matching function for call to 
'_quicksort(inkist<int>::iterator&, inkist<int>::iterator&)'
   _quicksort(headfish, tailfish);

quicksort.h:36:33: note: candidate is:
quicksort.h:40:13: note: template<class listclass> void _quicksort (class
listclass::iterator&, class listclass::iterator&)
  inline void _quicksort(class listclass::iterator& headfish, class
listclass::iterator& tailfish)

quicksort.h:40:13: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed.
quicksort.h:36:33: note: couldn't deduce template parameter 'listclass'
   _quicksort(headfish, tailfish);
```

Here's my code:

```
#ifndef _quicksort_h_included_
#define _quicksort_h_included_


#include <iterator>

template <class listclass>
inline void swap(class listclass::iterator& onefish, class listclass::iterator& twofish)
{
   class listclass::const_iterator tempfish;
   *tempfish=*onefish
   *onefish=*twofish;
   *twofish=*tempfish;
};

template <class listclass>
inline void quicksort (listclass& redlist)
{
   class listclass::iterator headfish;
   headfish=redlist.begin();
   class listclass::iterator tailfish;
   tailfish=redlist.end();

   _quicksort(headfish, tailfish);
};

template <class listclass>
inline void _quicksort(class listclass::iterator& headfish, class listclass::iterator& tailfish)
{
   if (headfish.P!=tailfish.P && headfish.P!=tailfish.P->next)
   {
      class listclass::iterator itrfish = partition(headfish, tailfish);
      class listclass::iterator lowfish(itrfish.P->prev);
      class listclass::iterator highfish(itrfish.P->next);

      _quicksort(headfish, lowfish);
      _quicksort(highfish, tailfish);
   }
};

template <class listclass>
inline class listclass::iterator partition(class listclass::iterator& headfish, class listclass::iterator& tailfish)
{
   class listclass::iterator datafish;
   *datafish=*headfish;

   class listclass::iterator pvtfish(headfish.P->prev);
   class listclass::iterator sortfish;

   for (sortfish.P=headfish.P; sortfish.P!=tailfish.P; sortfish.P=sortfish.P->next)
   {
      if(*sortfish<=*datafish)
      {
         if (sortfish.P==0)
            sortfish.P=headfish.P;
         else
            sortfish.P++;

         swap(&sortfish, &pvtfish);
      }
   }
   if (sortfish.P==0)
      sortfish.P=headfish.P;
   else
      sortfish.P++;

   swap(&sortfish, &tailfish);

   return sortfish;
};



#endif
```

From my understanding, after researching this problem and reading through the solutions other people have received, I'm somehow messing directly with my listclass outside of the template declaration. According to the compiler, I think it happens when my main quicksort function calls the recursive function? I'm not entirely sure what it is that I've done that has caused this issue.

Now, this is sort of my first time experimenting with template functions like this, with calling another class through a template. I wouldn't be surprised if there's actually a lot of mistakes in this, while it's only showing me the one. If anybody can also inform me of any other mistakes I have made with this attempt, please include those as well.

Comment: The short answer is that everything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context, and so the compiler can't figure out what `listclass` is. Template your function on the iterator's type, not the container's.

Comment: You can't deduce a template argument from a nested type. The simple reason is the same nested type may exist in multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class listclass>
inline void _quicksort(class listclass::iterator& headfish, class listclass::iterator& tailfish);
```

Here `listclass` is used in a "non deduced context".  It cannot be deduced from the function arguments by any means.

So one solution would be to specify it instead of trying to make the compiler deduce it:

```
template <class listclass>
inline void quicksort (listclass& redlist)
{
   // ...

   _quicksort<listclass>(headfish, tailfish);
};
```

Or, you could change `_quicksort` like this:

```
template <class FwdIter>
inline void _quicksort(FwdIter& headfish, FwdIter& tailfish);
```

and then `FwdIter` can be deduced.

Comment: isn't it better to use `typename` instead of `class` everywhere too?

Comment: @dwcanillas That's purely a matter of preference.

Comment: @dwcanillas: There are a few narrow edge cases where one is better that the other.

Comment: Adding <listclass> seems to have fixed that problem; however, now I'm getting errors saying that "'_quicksort' was not declared in this scope", and "excpected primary-expression before '>' token." I would try it the other way you posted, but I'm not sure what FwdIter is supposed to refer to, and my iterator is nested within my linked list class.